# Ngnix Passanger Ruby cannot load such file -- bundler/setup (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger

I'm trying to install a Ruby Rails app on my ngnix server but after I installed: Redis, NodeJs, Ruby, Postgres, Passenger it keeps showing

```
/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- bundler/setup (LoadError)
from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /var/www/umbrella/config/boot.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
from bin/rails:3:in `require_relative'
from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

I have the following settings:

```
gem env
```

returns

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.7.6
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.5.1 (2018-03-29 patchlevel 57) [x86_64-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/work/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0
  - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/work/.gem/ruby/2.5.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /home/work/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /home/work/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /home/work/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /home/work/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/etc
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /home/work/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0
     - /home/work/.gem/ruby/2.5.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /home/work/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/bin
     - /home/work/.rbenv/libexec
     - /home/work/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin
     - /home/work/bin
     - /home/work/.local/bin
     - /home/work/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin
     - /home/work/.rbenv/shims
     - /home/work/.rbenv/bin
     - /usr/local/sbin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /usr/bin
     - /sbin
     - /bin
     - /usr/games
     - /usr/local/games
     - /snap/bin
```

```
ruby -rbundler -e 'puts $LOAD_PATH'
```

```
/home/work/.rbenv/rbenv.d/exec/gem-rehash
/home/work/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/did_you_mean-1.2.0/lib
/home/work/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.16.4/lib
/home/work/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0
/home/work/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/x86_64-linux
/home/work/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby
/home/work/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.5.0
/home/work/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.5.0/x86_64-linux
/home/work/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby
/home/work/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0
/home/work/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/x86_64-linux
```

and the passanger config file:

```
/etc/nginx/passenger.conf
```

```
passenger_root /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/locations.ini;
passenger_ruby /home/work/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/bin/ruby;
#passenger_ruby /usr/bin/passenger_free_ruby;
```

also, if I run

```
which passenger-config
```

I'll recive

```
/usr/bin/passenger-config
```

and

```
/usr/bin/passenger-config  --ruby-command
```

```
passenger-config was invoked through the following Ruby interpreter:
  Command: /home/work/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/bin/ruby
  Version: ruby 2.5.1p57 (2018-03-29 revision 63029) [x86_64-linux]
  To use in Apache: PassengerRuby /home/work/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/bin/ruby
  To use in Nginx : passenger_ruby /home/work/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/bin/ruby
  To use with Standalone: /home/work/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/bin/ruby /usr/bin/passenger start

The following Ruby interpreter was found first in $PATH:
  Command: /home/work/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/bin/ruby
  Version: ruby 2.5.1p57 (2018-03-29 revision 63029) [x86_64-linux]
  To use in Apache: PassengerRuby /home/work/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/bin/ruby
  To use in Nginx : passenger_ruby /home/work/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/bin/ruby
  To use with Standalone: /home/work/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/bin/ruby /usr/bin/passenger start
```

I checked the passenger oficial documentation and I followed their steps, but still I'm not able to go through this

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you run `bundle install` as the app's superuser (while in the app's directory)?